# pull data from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

how is it possible to pull out complete country name from table 'Country' if I already have countrie's short name (FR, US, CA) but accordance between short name and full name is located in table 'Country'. For example I need to add there Fr = France, US=United States, etc. This is request which I make:

```
select 
initcap(split_part(man.email,'@',1)) as manager,
uu.country ,
uu.id as id,
uu.email as email,
array_agg(distinct case when aa.status=2 then aa.id||': '||aa.url else null end) as sites,
uu.created_at,
case
        when uu.status=0 then 'Inactive'
        when uu.status=1 then 'Approved'
        when uu.status=2 then 'Pending'
        when uu.status=3 then 'Closed'
        else 'Unknown'
end as account_status
from users_user uu
left join applications_application aa on uu.id=aa.publisher_id
left join users_user man on uu.account_manager_id=man.id
where uu.roles&&'{1}'
and split_part(man.email,'@',1) in ('Sasha_K','wolf','Century','ersac')
group by 1,2,3,6;
```

This is what I get now from request:
[image: This is what I get now from request:]

This is what I need to get:
[image: This is what I need to get]

When I change request to following:

```
    select 
initcap(split_part(man.email,'@',1)) as manager,
uu.country ,
uu.id as id,
uu.email as email,
types_country.country_full ,
array_agg(distinct case when aa.status=2 then aa.id||': '||aa.url else null end) as sites,
uu.created_at,
case
        when uu.status=0 then 'Inactive'
        when uu.status=1 then 'Approved'
        when uu.status=2 then 'Pending'
        when uu.status=3 then 'Closed'
        else 'Unknown'
end as account_status
from users_user uu
left join applications_application aa on uu.id=aa.publisher_id
left join users_user man on uu.account_manager_id=man.id
left join types_country tc on uu.country=types_country.country_code 
where uu.roles&&'{1}'
and split_part(man.email,'@',1) in ('Sasha_K','wolf','Century','ersac')
group by 1,2,3,6;
```

then I see there error message

> SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "types_country"

How is it necessary to change request to pull correct data?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: ... and simplify - [mcve].

Comment: @eshirvana dear eshirvana I have edited question please take a look there.

Comment: Postgres cannot convert a country name for you.  You need to provide another table that lists country code in one column, and country name in another column, then join your existing query against that mapping table

Comment: you still has not provide sample data ,but why not just join it with country table. what's the problem?

Comment: Hello @eshirvana When I make a join I see data as You can see it in the topic. How is it possible to change the request ?